# Change link based on option box

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a webpage for downloading one of my apps using bootstrap. I'm trying to make a download page, and have some options on it, and I need the download link to change depending on what options are selected. I have the gui, but I really have no knowledge on how to make the link change.

My code so far is like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xdragonforce/2fta6/

Thanks!

Comment: What's the difference between 521N, and 521U?

Comment: you can set value of variable withing page-scope, and then on submit build the link dynamically according to variables contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would achieve what you're asking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeLink(newHref)
{
    downloadBtn.href = newHref;
    if (newHref == "")
        downloadBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    else
        downloadBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'false');
}
</script>
<style>
#downloadBtn
{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #49AFCD;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
}
#downloadBtn:hover
{
    background-color: #2F96B4;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Select your device</h2>
    <select id='m_List1' onchange='changeLink(this.value);'>
        <option value="" selected>Select an device type</option>
        <option value="http://sourceforge.net/projects/whited00r/files/5.2.1/Whited00r_521N_iPhone2G.zip/download">iPhone 2G (521N)</option>
        <option value="http://sourceforge.net/projects/whited00r/files/5.2.1/Whited00r_521U_iPhone2G.zip/download">iPhone 2G (521U)</option>

        <option value="http://sourceforge.net/projects/whited00r/files/5.2.1/Whited00r_521N_iPhone3G.zip/download">iPhone 3G (521N)</option>
        <option value="http://sourceforge.net/projects/whited00r/files/5.2.1/Whited00r_521U_iPhone3G.zip/download">iPhone 3G (521U)</option>

        <option value="http://sourceforge.net/projects/whited00r/files/5.2.1/Whited00r_521_iPodTouch1G.zip/download">iPadTouch 1G</option>
        <option value="http://sourceforge.net/projects/whited00r/files/5.2.1/Whited00r_521_iPodTouch2G.zip/download">iPadTouch 2G</option>
    </select>
    <a id='downloadBtn' disabled='true'>Download »</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You pass these parameters normally using the form, and have the server to parse the URL parameters and send/redirect to the appropriate file. This isn't HTML's job.

You need to:

- Use a `<form>` element, that submits to a server-side (PHP, ASP, etc) page, which can process it.
- Give your `<select>` elements `name=` attributes, which represent their roll in the form.
- On the processing page, you take the form parameters which were selected by the user, process them, determine the correct version of the file you want to give, and serve it (or redirect to the page which serves it).

Comment: I'll look into that then, thanks:) Do you reckon there's a way to do this with Javascript?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but it would be better to do so on the server-side. Since the user can't temper with it and get a file version he doesn't need, or worse, isn't authorized to access.